# Excel Countifs date column not empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to count number of external employees. 
There are two columns,

Column F with values EXT for external and INT for internal employees

Column G with date.

Now, if date column is empty this means that employee is here since last year. I need this as my starting point for my other calculations, i.e. how this number changed through months of this year. 
So this is what i found in different sources, but this formula is returning 0

```
=(COUNTIFS(F2:F130;"EXT";G2:G130;">"))
```

i guess that there is error in second criteria

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, but this should work -

```
=(COUNTIFS(F2:F130;"EXT";G2:G130;""))
```

No need for the `>` - just use the `""` as the criteria for blanks.

Answer (score 0):

With coumn B randomly inserted "ext" or "int" and in column C the date, I counted the numbers of "ext" compared to a specific date; i.e. in cell C14.
I had a count of 57. The trick was to compare the cells with a designated cell.

=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$113;"ext";$C$1:$C$113;">"&C14)

Or if you want to count the empt cells, then use "" (two colons) instead of ">"&C14.

=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$113;"ext";$C$1:$C$113;"")

I hope this will help you out.

Daan

Comment: Thanks, but i don't need to compare it to specific date, i just need to count numer of rows witf column F value EXT and column G empty

Comment: Then use "" (two colons) instead of ">"&C14. I changed this in the answer I already gave.

Comment: You mean two quotes (""), not two colons (::)